# Isometry of hyperbolic plane

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

I'm trying to prove the following statement: "every isometry of the hyperbolic plane has a fixed point, given that its orbit is bounded". Can someone help me with that?

Comment: What do you mean "orbit"?

Comment: "Bounded orbit" means that the set $\{T^n(z)\}$ is bounded for every $z$ as $n$ goes through the natural numbers.